# inserting a SPAN into a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to insert a HTML span element into a DIV element using Javascript

```
<div id='mydiv'>
</div>
```

I have a basic DIV, and i insert some text into the DIV. Inside this text i want to insert a SPAN.

```
var str = "insert me here %1 ok ";

var s = document.createElement('span');
s.innerHTML ="<span id='mySpan'>yes</span>";

str = str.replace('%1', s.toString);

$('#mydiv').html(str);
```

Everything I have tried, either I get the whole innerHTML quoted in a string, or i get [object OBJECT] or i get 'undefined' errors.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Gu8tw/1/

thanks!

Comment: I am assuming you don't want to use jQuery. If jQuery is being used then `$('#mydiv').append('#myspan');`

Comment: `$('#mydiv').html(str);` is jQuery. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but ="<span id='mySpan'>yes</span>"; is syntactically wrong for HTML, and the quotes should be swapped.  Double quotes for the HTML bits, and single quotes to wrap the string in?

(doesn't solve ur problem, just something I noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of wrong `s.toString()` you should use `s.outerHTML`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Gu8tw/2/